# Trirand jqgrid for asp.net - load drop down values when editing rows

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqgrid from trirand (asp.net version) and cannot work out how to simply load values for a drop down list from a web method when editing a cell.

Every example I have found on the internet is creating the grid completely from javascript which is NOT what I want to do.

markup for the grid is as follows:

```
   <tri:JQGrid runat="server" ID="jqgStockItems" Height="400px">
                    <Columns>
                        <tri:JQGridColumn HeaderText="Code" DataField="StockItemCode" DataType="System.String">
                        </tri:JQGridColumn>
                        <tri:JQGridColumn DataField="Description" DataType="System.String" HeaderText="Name">
                        </tri:JQGridColumn>
                        <tri:JQGridColumn DataField="SupplierPartNo" DataType="System.String" HeaderText="Supplier Part No">
                        </tri:JQGridColumn>
                        <tri:JQGridColumn DataField="ProductGroupDescription" DataType="System.String" HeaderText="Product Group">
                        </tri:JQGridColumn>
                        <tri:JQGridColumn DataField="BuyingUnitDescription" DataType="System.String" HeaderText="Buying Unit"
                            EditType="DropDown" Editable="True" >
                        </tri:JQGridColumn>
                        <tri:JQGridColumn DataField="UnitPrice" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" DataType="System.String"
                            HeaderText="Unit Price" TextAlign="Right" Editable="True">
                        </tri:JQGridColumn>
                        <tri:JQGridColumn DataField="Quantity" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" DataType="System.Decimal"
                            Editable="True" HeaderText="Quantity" TextAlign="Right" Width="100">
                        </tri:JQGridColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerSettings PageSize="100000" />
                    <ToolBarSettings ShowSearchToolBar="True">
                    </ToolBarSettings>
                    <EditInlineCellSettings Enabled="True" />
                </tri:JQGrid>
```

as you can see my buying unit description is the column which has a drop down edit control. I need to populate this per row as the options are differnet per row.

How can I do this with the asp.net version of the grid without setting the grid up in javascript. Surely this must be possible!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok worked it out.

if anyone wants the solution I wrote it here:

[Load dropdowns dynamically](http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-load-drop-down-in-jqgrid-with.html)